# Lotusscript to insert a Subform into a Form programmatically

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus-notes

I am trying to deploy a Domino application in a possibly friendly way. I've got to the point where an agent imports Domino elements.

The functionality I'd like to provide is in a subform which I could export and import.
I still need to insert the SubForm in a specific location in an already existing Domino application.

I didn't find any API that could be helpful. Is there a way to access and modify the code of an already existing form directly?

Comment: The only way I knew is to change the dxl (Domino XML Language) of the form. So you have to program an export of the form in dxl, change the dxl(insert sub-form) and import the dxl. you can view the dxl of a form via lotus Notes Desgin > =8.5.1. open the Java perspective in teh designer, an then open the form via xml editor.

Comment: Csan you explain why you are not simply doing this manually? Even if there are multiple instaces of the application, this is what inheritance from a template is for. I'd like to understand why that's not sufficient for what you are trying to do.

Comment: The problem is with the deployment. I am trying to minimalize the effort required from the client to import my changes into the mail application she is already using.

Comment: I still don't get why you aren't just rolling out a new template onto the server. Is this an extenstion to a set of customizations that have previously been made to the standard mail template in some other organization where you don't have access to the servers?

Comment: Yes Exactly.   I have to do changes on my machine and deploy it on another, to which I have know access. So I have to provide some kind of ready-to-use packaging.

Answer (score 3):

DXL round-tripping of forms isn't perfect, so I wouldn't recommend using it in the way adminfd describes. You can, however, write C/C++ code that uses the Notes C API functions to scan through the CD records of a form and insert a subform reference. CD records are complex and you would probably want an expert to assist, to make sure you don't screw up your form by inserting your stuff in the wrong spot.